# Wrap specific field on each line

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

file:

```
DocumentNameA varying number of words symbols etc
DocumentName2 varying number of words symbols etc
AnotherDocumentName varying number of words symbols etc
```

I want to do something like

```
sed -i 's/$1/"<opentag>"$1"</closetag>"/' file
```

To have file change to

```
<opentag>DocumentNameA</closetag> varying number of words symbols etc
<opentag>DocumentName2</closetag> varying number of words symbols etc
<opentag>AnotherDocumentName</closetag> varying number of words symbols etc
```

Seems there has got to be a straightforward way of doing this, but I have not found it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get closer to your suggested syntax using awk - either

```
awk '{$1 = "<opentag>" $1 "</closetag>"} 1' file
```

or

```
awk '{$1 = sprintf("<opentag>%s</closetag>", $1)} 1' file
```

GNU awk has a `-i inplace` switch, equivalent of sed's `-i`, so for example:

```
gawk -i inplace '{$1 = "<opentag>" $1 "</closetag>"} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\1` to refer to the matching sub-expressions in the regex:

```
 sed -Ei 's:^([^ ]+):"<opentag>\1</closetag>":' file
```

Comment: That worked, although I changed it to ```sed -Ei 's:^([^ ]+):<opentag>\1</closetag>:' file``` (removed double quote)